# How do I prove that $\sigma_x(n)=n^x+1$ implies $n$ is a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x$ be a complex number and $\sigma_x$ be the divisor function.

How do I prove that $\sigma_x(n)=n^x +1 \Rightarrow n\text{ is a prime}$?

When $x$ is real it is easy, but seems like the problem becomes really hard when $x$ is complex.

Comment: What's the definition of $\sigma_x$? If it involves a sum over divisors, then I bet the only thing you need to use is that if $n$ is prime then the only divisors $n$ has are $n$ and $1$.

Comment: $\sigma_x(n)=\sum_{d|n} d^x$

Comment: @GerryMyerson That direction is trivial. I'm asking another direction just for curiosity

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is false.

Take $n=8$ and $x = \frac{\pi i}{\log 2}$. Then $2^x = -1$, thus $$1^x + 2^x + 4^x + 8^x = 1^x + 2^x(2^x+ 1) + 8^x = 8^x +1.$$

Comment: nice one! thank you :))